# lvh.me not working - following railscasts revised Ep. 123

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All, is anyone else having a problem using lvh.me? 
Trying to follow railscasts 123 (the revised one) but firefox (and iceweasel for that matter) do not resolve, error msg is 'server not found'.

Have turned off domain guessing (through about:config), and tried several domains: `www.lvh.me:3000`, `lvh.me:3000`, with/without http://.. etc.

Note `http://localhost:3000` is working just fine, rails server/app are running - everything else seems healthy. Is lvh.me still alive and resolves to 127.0.0.1?

Thoughts?

Comment: it was a little slow this morning.  if I remember correctly, that's the subdomain railscast right? i suggest you add entries to your hosts file instead.  this is faster and doesn't need the internet to resolve to localhost

Comment: thanks, jvnill - any pointer on how to bypass lvh.me and add entries to the hosts file? And yes, it is the subdomain railscast episode.

Comment: if you are in a linux distro, the hosts file is in /etc/hosts. just edit that and add a line to localhost

Comment: https://notopening.com/site/lvh.me

Comment: oh, this is why! i've been trying to resolve this for nearly 8 years, thanks @OshanWisumperuma!